VisualVM Error: Local Applications Cannot Be Detected
I'm trying to run my Java Program via Eclipse with the IDE Integration of VisualVM.
Installation was successful and I also added VisualVM on the run configurations.
Upon running I encountered an error message: Local Applications Cannot Be Detected (Error Dialog On Startup)
Based on the troubleshooting guide, I made sure that the following are present:

Insufficient permissions for %TMP%\hsperfdata_username - Set the folder permission for my user to read/write
Having %TMP%\hsperfdata_username folder on a FAT disk - Added XX:+PerfBypassFileSystemCheck for my VM arguments

Yet, still I'm encountering the same error.
Upon checking %TMP%\hsperfdata_username is empty. Is there any steps I've missed during the setup?
